# How can I send cookie while using REST API?

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel 5 and trying to send some data from my site to another one, which provides me with the REST API. But they use cookies as a authorization. For this moment, I've passed auth successfully. And stuck on how should I send this cookie to API interface via POST method? Here is my listing.

Thanx in advance.

P.S. All things are going on inside the controller.

```
if (Cookie::get('amoauth') !== null) {
            //COOKIE IS HERE
            $client = new Client();
            $newlead = $client->post('https://domain.amocrm.ru/private/api/v2/json/leads/set', [
                'add' => [
                    'add/name' => 'TEST LEAD',
                    'add/date_create' => time(),
                    'add/last_modified' => time(),
                    'add/status_id' => '1',
                    'add/price' => 5000
                ]
            ]);
        } else {
            $client = new Client();
            $auth = $client->post('https://domain.amocrm.ru/private/api/auth.php',[
                'USER_LOGIN' => 'login',
                'USER_HASH' => 'hash',
                'type' => 'json'
            ]);
            $auth = $auth->getHeaders('Set-Cookie');
            Cookie::queue('amoauth', $auth, 15);
            return redirect('/test');
        }
```

Now it returns me the following:

```
Client error: `POST https://domain.amocrm.ru/private/api/v2/json/leads/set` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response.
```

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1400 but still no idea how to implement it (the same situation is described via this link).

Comment: Tried to use `CookieJar: $jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar(Cookie::get('amoauth'));` but still getting `401 Unauthorized`... Maybe I've failed while getting and storing this cookie from API provider?

Comment: This is what I get after successful auth from API provider: [link](https://pastebin.com/PECa1xdv). And this is stored cookie: [link](https://pastebin.com/PDVBiwNh). Any ideas are appreciated for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: switched to `ixudra/curl`.